# swift present controller with a back button to get back to last screen

Tags: swift, xcode

I am presenting a UICollectionViewController but it just ends up as a controller with no back buttons to get back to the last controller or the home controller, how would i add a back button? or what other options do i have?

```
class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UserProfileHeaderDelegate, ProfileHeaderClosedDelegate {


func presentFRC() {
       let PE = FriendsRequestsController(collectionViewLayout: 
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    let NPE = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PE)

    self.present(NPE, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: did you embedded it into uinavigatinController

Comment: I am not using story board, it is all done programmatically?

Comment: did you make your view controller as root view controller of a navigation controller and then you have to make that navigation controller root view controller of application

Comment: i can get to  UserProfileController and it has a back button when i come from class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UISearchBarDelegate   though at the moment i am coming from a header in a uicollectionview?

Comment: can you add code

Comment: May I ask why you've chosen to do this programmatically rather than use the Storyboard.  With the Storyboard, this could be done very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in the view did load of the view controller you are presenting.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
var backbutton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
backbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "BackButton.png"), forState: .Normal)
backbutton.setTitle("Back", forState: .Normal)
backbutton.setTitleColor(backbutton.tintColor, forState: .Normal) // You can change the TitleColor
backbutton.addTarget(self, action: "backAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton)
}

func backAction() -> Void {        
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Embed your view controllers into `UINavigationController` and use `UINavigationBar` and segues for navigation. The easiest way to build such a system would be through storyboard though. But you can do that programmatically as well, but it would be a lot more work.
2. Add your own back button programmatically the way **@ZahurafzalMirza** has shown you. Since you are not using `UINavigationController`, your `navigationController` will be `nil`. So the action should look like this

   ```
   func backAction() -> Void {        
       self.dismiss(animated: true)
   }
   ```