# Not able to add back button to swift navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have issue where my app has a screen that scans a UPC code and shows the product detail screen if a match found, however the screen shows up as a modal and there is no back button, it looks like this and if I make it full screen you can't leave this screen.

[Screen without back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qoee.png)

Here is it looks when accessing via the search screen

[Here is how it should look with back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th1Y2.png)

Here is the code I'm using the present the product detail screen:

```
func launchApp(decodedURL: String) {
    
    if presentedViewController != nil {
        return
    }
    
    let decodedUPC = Int(decodedURL)
    
    guard let goodProduct = ProductsProvider().queryUPC(upcNumber: decodedUPC!) else  {
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UPC Code not found \(String(describing: decodedUPC))", message: "We could not find this item, please use our search", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            
            // Code here
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        })
        
        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
        
    }
            

    let viewController:
        ProductDetailView = UIStoryboard(
            name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: ProductDetailView.self)
            ).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productDetailViewController") as! ProductDetailView
    
    viewController.productDetail = goodProduct
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
    viewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    // navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

    

    self.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Any help to get the back button on the screen would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610916.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#Method 1**

From Apple documentation regarding to **pushViewController(_:animated:)** [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller):

> In addition to displaying the view associated with the new view
> controller at the top of the stack, this method also updates the
> navigation bar and tool bar accordingly.

To update your navigation bar and tool bar in order to show the back button you should push the **viewController** from your existing navigation controller:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

instead of:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**#Method 2**

To dismiss a full screen presented **ViewController** simply add a **UIBarButtonItem** to the navigationItem:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Presented View"

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))
    }

    @objc func cancelAction() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pushViewController approach instead of present:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier_of_target_vc") as! ClassNameofTargetVC 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)
```

Hope this helps!